Nginx Ingress: Canary deployments not working with ingress-name, working with Kubernetes service name
I am trying out nginx-ingress canary services via Header-value. So, basically, if I have the header nginx-1, if ingress domain is called, it should go to nginx-1 service. But I keep getting a 404 regardless. If I replace the domain with Kubernetes service name, then it works just fine. What am I doing wrong?
Manifest file
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-canary-ingress
  namespace: test-istio
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary-by-header: "route"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary-by-header-pattern: "nginx-[1-4]"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.cloud.test-domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /nginx
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx-default
            port: 
              number: 80
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-1-ingress
  namespace: test-istio
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary-by-header: "route"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary-by-header-value: "nginx-1"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.cloud.test-domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /nginx
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx-1
            port: 
              number: 80
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-2-ingress
  namespace: test-istio
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary-by-header: "route"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary-by-header-value: "nginx-2"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.cloud.test-domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /nginx
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx-2
            port: 
              number: 80
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-3-ingress
  namespace: test-istio
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary-by-header: "route"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary-by-header-value: "nginx-3"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.cloud.test-domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /nginx
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx-3
            port: 
              number: 80
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-4-ingress
  namespace: test-istio
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary-by-header: "route"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary-by-header-value: "nginx-4"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.cloud.test-domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /nginx
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx-4
            port: 
              number: 80

Curl call:
kubectl exec -it curl-test -n test-istio -- curl -H "Host: test.cloud.test-domain.com" -H "route: nginx-1" http://test.cloud.test-domain.com.test-istio/nginx

Thank you.

@ We are Borg Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your problem? If the answer was useful, please mark the answer as accepted for greater visibility for the community or upvote if the answer has some useful information.

Sorry, My bad, I was working on another topic, I will update you tomorrow definitely. :-)

@ We are Borg I am looking forward to your feedback to understand whether the provided information has helped you in resolving the issue. If not, I am happy to assist further.

From your manifest files and description, you have multiple ingress resources, each handling canary traffic based on the ‘route’ header. The reason for receiving a 404 error usually indicates that the ingress configuration is not correctly to the intended service. You need to define a single Ingress resource that handles all the canary routing.
Make sure the DNS entry for ‘test.cloud.test-domain.com’ is correctly pointing to your NGINX ingress controller’s IP address, also verify services(nginx-default and nginx1-4) are reachable with ‘test-istio’ namespace and accessible on port 80.
Remove the canary ingress, and add primary ingress for default traffic. It doesn’t include any canary annotations. Add remaining Canary ingress resource service(nginx1,nginx2,nginx3,nginx4) should be the same, which is configured to handle specific canary traffic.
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-default-ingress
  namespace: test-istio
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.cloud.test-domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /nginx
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx-default
            port: 
              number: 80

— remaining service(nginx1-4)
In Curl call: Instead of this
kubectl exec -it curl-test -n test-istio -- curl -H "Host: test.cloud.test-domain.com" -H "route: nginx-1" http://test.cloud.test-domain.com.test-istio/nginx

Try below
kubectl exec -it curl-test-istio -- curl -H "Host: test.cloud.test-domain.com" -H "route: nginx-1" http://test.cloud.test-domain.com/nginx

Test-istio- unnecessary
Another Way: By using ‘rewrite-target’ annotations. by adding below annotation

nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /

for both default traffic and all the services.
